# Adding Progress bar in Global application in android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I would like to load progress bar when loading the application. I have 60 sound files which I have put in global application using sound pool. When I launch the application the application goes blank and it takes 30 to 40 seconds to load.

Instead of blank screen is it possible to put some progress bar with a background image until the application loads all the sound files?

I found out the global application doesn't support progress bar or background image? Is this true?

If not can somebody help me out in the above?

Thanks!

Comment: use a AsyncTask for this

Comment: Where do I use AsyncTask in new layout because i believe application class doesn't support AsyncTask or probably I am wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Load your sound files in an AsyncTask or a Thread.

You can set an `OnLoadCompleteListener` to know exactly when loading finishes.

Comment: But I am using application class for calling the object globally. I think the application class doesn't support AsyncTask?

Comment: You can execute an `AsyncTask` inside your `Application`.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't. Did you try it?

Comment: Hi paradx - you said inside your application - what do you mean by that ? you mean inside application class or inside each activity?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, and you mean your `Application` class, than you can't show a progressbar from there. But you have to have at least one activity, and you can show progressbars in your activity.

Also, you shouldn't make heavy operations on the UI thread such as this. Load the sounds in an `AsyncTask`, show the progressbar in the `onPreExecute()` method and hide it in the `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: Are you saying load the sound files when ever required using AsyncTask but it takes time to do every time hence I decided to load the sounds on launch on application and then just call them whenever required.

Comment: No, I say load all your sounds when you first start your application, but don't do it on the UI thread, instead implement it in an `AsyncTask` and call that `AsyncTask` once on the first application start.